# Application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality when it converts to equality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am leading with the following proof:

"Given two triangles of sides $a,b,c$ and $a',b'c'$, prove that they are similar iff

$$\sqrt{aa'}+\sqrt{bb'}+\sqrt{cc'}=\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a'+b'+c')}$$

I have already proved the direct implication but I am struggling with the inverse one. I need to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in that one (when it is converted into an equality when the vectors are linearly dependent) but I don't get this equality. Any hint? Which vectors may I take? Thanks.

Comment: What are you missing? 1: knowing in which case CSI is an equality, or 2: applying this knowledge?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality's both sides are equal **iff** the vectors are linearly dependent.